# Best practice for google spreadsheet multiple cell evaluation and output result

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

i'm looking for a better solution for my spreadsheet problem.
i have multiple input values i can activate using the checkbox feature. now if one checkbox is clicked the output is as following:

> **text value1**

if a second checkbox is clicked the output gets stacked:

> **text value1 value2**

and so on

the solution i found is creating a huge **IF** string that evaluates every possible checkbox combination. however this is very inefficient the more checkboxes there are.

here is my solution with only two checkboxes:

```
=IF(AND($A$1=TRUE,$A$2=FALSE),"text value1",IF(AND($A$1=FALSE,$A$2=TRUE),"text value2",IF(AND($A$1=TRUE,$A$2=TRUE),"text value1 value2",IF(TRUE,"none"))))
```

it's a fast solution for two cells but is there a way to have these values in an array and add them to the **text** instead of evaluating every possible combination or is this the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("text "&TEXTJOIN(" ",1,IF(A1:A2,B1:B2,)))
```

- IF to get  corresponding "value" from the array B1:B2
- TEXTJOIN to join resulting "value"s